# Prerequisites for Halliday Resnick Walker

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I am in grade 10.
I have developed an interest in physics but unfortunately I do not know/ have not studied calculus yet as my school board does not recommend it in grade 10.
I have a copy of fundamentals of physics, [Halliday Resnick Walker](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=halliday+resnick+walker), I read chapter's one and two briefly and I understood the conceptual part.
But when it came to derivation's of the equation's I couldnt understand it.
Please, can you recommend any book/video lecture to solve this problem.

Comment: [*Khan Academy*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus) is hard to beat. Just be sure, when you take calculus in school, that you are humble, and take the material at the rate it is taught, even if you know it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately if you want to read Haliday, Resnick, Walker, you'll need to learn calculus. If you're motivated, it's entirely do-able on your own. Have a look at Khan Academy's tutorials. How long it takes to get to the level required for HRW will depend how much mathematics you know already.

You can learn some physics without hardcore calculus though. Start with popular physics and Khan academy (again). Let the things you learn from these sources motivate you to learn more mathematics, which in turn will allow you to learn more physics.

Does your high-school have a physics cirriculum? If not, you could look up what they learn in another school system - for example, A-level physics in the United kingdom, or the international baccelauriate. These courses will be designed to get you a good grounding in physics without needing to know lots of mathematics.

Comment: Yep. I highly second this answer. I followed the same path, trying Resnick Halliday and Walker with much math. Then I realized (especially from MIT OCW - Walter Lewin's Physics lectures) calculus is a must. So I went back and started learning right from Arithemetic and Pre-Algebra at http://KhanAcademy.org .They're math practise software is an adaptive system and while I thought I was half decent at high school math, 6th grade math kicked my butt. I'm still on this path now and am determined to learn calculus all the way then `HRW` is all mine!